# Swift array seems to not be appending

Tags: arrays, swift, xcode, dictionary, append

This question is pretty elementary but I am a beginner to Swift and any help would be appreciated. I am building an app where when the user presses a button from the menu page, it appends an array, adding the name of the item the user added to their cart. The cart page is supposed to display what is in the array on a text view or label, but it looks like the arrays are not appending. I have compared this app to a previous app I built that worked similarly and can't find a reason why this one is not working.

I have tried appending, adding the elements at the 0 spot in the array, using dictionaries, I created separate classes, I am not sure what else to try. I also tried appending with just a string (shown in the tropTwistButtonPushed func) and appending using the text in a label (shown in the other "button pushed" functions).

```
// arrays //
var smoothieNames : [String] = []
var smoothiePrices : [Double] = []

@IBAction func tropTwistButtonPushed(_ sender: Any) {
    // add items to the arrays
    smoothieNames.append("Tropical Twist")
    smoothiePrices.append(4.00)
}

@IBAction func berryButtonPushed(_ sender: Any) {
    smoothieNames.append(berryYummyLabel.text ?? "")
    smoothiePrices.append(3.00)
}

@IBAction func chiliMangoButtonPushed(_ sender: Any) {
    smoothieNames.append(chiliMangoLabel.text ?? "")
    smoothiePrices.append(4.00)
}


@IBAction func pbNanaButtonPushed(_ sender: Any) {
    smoothieNames.append(pbNanaLabel.text ?? "")
    smoothiePrices.append(3.00)
}
```

in a separate class and view controller:

```
@IBAction func refreshButtonTapped(_ sender: Any) {
    for smoothie in smoothieNames {
        smoothieNamesTextView.text += "\(smoothie) \n"
    }
```

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JN1hR.png)

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8IMur.png)

Comment: You are inheriting ViewController class to sencond class. That's why it's not working. Just pass data between two UIViewController subclass. Just search on google "How to pass data between two controller"

Comment: print `smoothieNames` just after he `append()` call. But seeing `in a separate class and view controller:`, how is passed the info from one to that other viewcontroller? Now, unrelated, but I'd avoid using two array which are supposed to be "synced" (meaning; element at index n is for the element at index n of the other array); instead, use an array of a custom struct.

Comment: @Larme it is not passed. OP is subclassing ViewController and has another instance (empty) of the smoothies

Comment: @LeoDabus I gave the author reasonable doubt, just in case that he/she was indeed passing the data from one VC to the other one, but badly (to a wrong instance etc.). But indeed, if he/she is expecting that subclassing is passing data, that's a wrong concept indeed.